# Markup Validation says divs are not closed but they are

Tags: html, validation, w3c

I'm working on a site http://hearthable.com and I'm testing the validation of it and it is saying that all my container divs are not closed such as my wrapper, and my main content containers.

Here is a link the the validation
http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fhearthable.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

If you view the sourcecode of the site you'll see that all the divs are closed, why does the validation do this and is there anyway I can correct it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the source code of your site I see that it is missing 3 `</div>` tags in the end, just like the validation says.

Ì suspect that an error in your php-file is cutting of some of the code.
(I can't tell for sure since I don't have access to it)

If you are using Google Chrome then remember that `Ctrl+Shift+J` shows Chrome's **interpretation** of your code. This means that it will add missing tags.

Press `Ctrl+U` to view the actual source code with the missing tags.

EDIT: It looks like you have fixed it now.